# How does svycoxph handle ties?

Tags: r, survey, survival-analysis, weighted, cox-regression

As far as I know, `coxph` handles ties by default, and there are 3 options for handling ties. I wonder how `svycoxph` in the survey package handles ties. Is it the same as `coxph`? There does not seem to be an option for this.

Nothing about ties is mentioned in CRAN and I couldn't find anything about it. Does anyone know about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For `svycoxph`, according to the documentation, it is possible to pass the arguments of `coxph` in 3 dots `...`

> ...   - For AIC, more models to compare the AIC of. For *svycoxph*, other arguments passed to *coxph*.

If we look at the arguments for `coxph`

```
args(coxph)
function (formula, data, weights, subset, na.action, init, control, 
    ties = c("efron", "breslow", "exact"), singular.ok = TRUE, 
    robust, model = FALSE, x = FALSE, y = TRUE, tt, method = ties, 
    id, cluster, istate, statedata, nocenter = c(-1, 0, 1), ...)
```

where the `ties` (by default "efron") is also assigned in the `method`

Also, by looking at the source code of one of the methods of `svycoxph`

```
getAnywhere("svycoxph.svyrep.design")

function (formula, design, subset = NULL, rescale = NULL, ..., 
    return.replicates = FALSE, na.action, multicore = getOption("survey.multicore")) 
{

...
...
if (full$method %in% c("efron", "breslow")) { ### here
        if (attr(full$y, "type") == "right") 
            fitter <- coxph.fit
        else if (attr(full$y, "type") == "counting") 
            fitter <- survival::agreg.fit
        else stop("invalid survival type")
    }
    else fitter <- survival::agexact.fit
    
...
```

Using a small reproducible example from the documentation of `svycoxph`

```
> svycoxph(Surv(time,status>0)~log(bili)+protime+albumin,design=rpbc, ties = "efron")
Call:
svycoxph.svyrep.design(formula = Surv(time, status > 0) ~ log(bili) + 
    protime + albumin, design = rpbc, ties = "efron")

              coef exp(coef) se(coef)      z        p
log(bili)  0.88592   2.42522  0.09838  9.005  < 2e-16
protime    0.24487   1.27745  0.09373  2.612  0.00899
albumin   -1.04298   0.35240  0.21966 -4.748 2.05e-06

Likelihood ratio test=NA  on 3 df, p=NA
n= 312, number of events= 144 
> svycoxph(Surv(time,status>0)~log(bili)+protime+albumin,design=rpbc, ties = "breslow")
Call:
svycoxph.svyrep.design(formula = Surv(time, status > 0) ~ log(bili) + 
    protime + albumin, design = rpbc, ties = "breslow")

              coef exp(coef) se(coef)      z       p
log(bili)  0.88527   2.42363  0.09834  9.002 < 2e-16
protime    0.24494   1.27754  0.09373  2.613 0.00897
albumin   -1.04112   0.35306  0.21992 -4.734 2.2e-06

Likelihood ratio test=NA  on 3 df, p=NA
n= 312, number of events= 144
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation! So if I understand it right, the ties handling setting of svycoxph is the same as coxph? And you can also specify ties in svycoxph?

Comment: @user10386405 There are 3 methods listed in `svycoxph` depending on the class of your object, the method is invoked.  The one I showed is the `svyrep.design`.  Your post didn't show all the details.  So, it is not that clear though.  The `ties` value passed is later used in `method`.  Also, the `svycoxph` calls the `coxph` internally

Comment: I know there are three methods in coxph (efron, breslow, exact) and efron is the default. Since coxph is called internally in svycoxph, the methods listed in svycoxph should be the same. Is it correct?

Comment: @user10386405 If you look at that `else` code it is calling `else fitter <- survival::agexact.fit`.  You may have to look at that function to see if there is any difference

Comment: Yes, the tie-handling is the same as in `survival::coxph`.  Note that for designs with replicate weights (`svyrep.design`) there is resampling to compute variance estimates and the resamples might have a different set of ties.